# How can I configure the "Run" button next to the editor tabs in VS Code for Python files?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have the following configuration in my `launch.json`:

```json
{
    "configurations": 
    [
    {
      "name": "Python: Current File",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "justMyCode": true,
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      "env": {"PYTHONPATH": "C:/repo/python"}
    }
    ]
}
```

With this, I can easily run and debug the current script from the Run/Debug side panel:

[image]

All good, so far. But now I'd like to also be able to directly run the script from the Run button on the editor tabs:

[image]

Unfortunately, this does not work. It runs the file, but the configuration from above is not taken.

**How can I add a configuration with `PYTHONPATH` etc. also for this Run button in the editor tabs?**

Comment: press `F5`, don't use the top right triangle button

Comment: @rioV8: I've heard that before in a different context, and it works. But what is the reason that it does not work with the button? Is there simply no way to configure how a script is run via the button?

Comment: I have no idea which command is bound to the triangle button, F5 is bound to the "run current launch configuration", you can't change the command of a button with settings

Answer (score 1):

Note that [***launch.json***](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations) only works for debugging. The triangle button in the upper right corner of the editor interface only runs or debugs the current script file, and does not apply the configuration in launch.

If you want to debug the file outside the ***Run and Debug*** panel and use *launch.json*, use the shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or the top menu `Run-->Run Without Debugging`.

[image]

As for the configuration of the play button in the upper right corner you mentioned, this has existed on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/20269), but not enough votes have been collected. If you are interested in this, you can continue to raise it and pay attention.

Comment: I believe this statement is not totally accurate.

Answer (score 0):

#### If you're using the Python Debugger extension

See https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_85#_github-copilot. Quoting:

> The [Python Debugger](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.debugpy) extension now has a configurable debug option under the **Run** button menu. When you select **Python Debugger: Debug using launch.json** and there is an existing `launch.json` in your workspace, it shows all the available debug configurations that you can pick to start the debugger. If there aren't any configurations, you are prompted to select a debug configuration template to use to create a `launch.json` file for your Python application.

#### If you're not using the Python Debugger extension

I'm pretty sure the Run Python File button invokes the same thing as the `Python: Run Python File in Terminal` command in the command palette, which- if I understand correctly- uses settings that start with `python.terminal.*`. The current list of those settings at the time of this writing is the following (shown with their default values):

```json
// Activate Python Environment in the current Terminal on load of the Extension.
"python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": false,

// Activate Python Environment in all Terminals created.
"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true,

// When executing a file in the terminal, whether to use execute in the file's directory, instead of the current open folder.
"python.terminal.executeInFileDir": false,

// When launching a python terminal, whether to focus the cursor on the terminal.
"python.terminal.focusAfterLaunch": false,

// Python launch arguments to use when executing a file in the terminal.
"python.terminal.launchArgs": [],
```

Note: docs on debugging Python can be found here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging.

There is a property in python-type launch configs called "purpose", where you can put "debug-in-terminal" in the array value, which seems to make it so the launch config will apply when use the "debug in terminal" mode of the play button at the top-right of the screen.

For commandline arguments, use the `python.terminal.launchArgs` setting. As for `PYTHONPATH`, that's an environment variable, so you'll have to modify each of `terminal.integrated.env.windows`, `terminal.integrated.env.osx`, `terminal.integrated.env.linux` in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson) (you can do it in the workspace or user settings.json file). Ex.

```json
"terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
    "FOO": "foo",
    "BAR": "hello",
    "BAZ": "baz",
},
// repeat for OSX and Windows (unfortunately, it's repetitive)
```

Note also that since the `Python: Run Python File in Terminal` feature attempts to reuse the terminal, and that you can't (as far as I know) change a process' environment variables after it has been created, you'll need to close that terminal to get changes you make to the `terminal.integrated.env.*` to get "picked up" (from the terminal being recreated, and the shell process along with it).

Note: There's a related issue ticket at: [Allow "Run Python File in Terminal" button to be configurable #11812](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/11812).